# Stor Java byte[] in postgre as bit(64)

Tags: java, database, postgresql

I have a table in postgre and also in mysql:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS FOO_bit_64(
    PK bigint primary key,
    x bit(64));
```

And I try to persist data from java code, we get data as byte[] for bit(64) type, and while persisting in mysql, I added code :

```
ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.wrap((byte[]) data);
Object xVal = precision <= 32 ?   buf.getInt() : buf.getLong();
```

this works, but the same is not working in Postgre.

Insert that is generated:

```
  INSERT INTO FOO_bit_64 (PK, X) VALUES (1,-8523372036854775808)
```

Error Message:

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "x" is of type bit but expression is of type bigint
Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.

Comment: What is your definition of "not working" ? And could you share the INSERT statement that is generated by your code?

Comment: From the manual: `Bit strings are strings of 1's and 0's.` The value -8523372036854775808 is clearly not a bit. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-bit.html